# Is there any dart package through which i can turn mobile data connection on or off and change phone from ring mode to silent for my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, phone-state-listener

**I  have attached a basic code the switch's on change value would trigger the event like turning off data, turning phone to silent when it's in on state**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Tutorial - googleflutter.com'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Switch(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                //turn phone data to off and change phone from ring mode to silent
              });
            },
            activeTrackColor: Colors.yellow,
            activeColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do what you're looking for. Since it requires telephony permission and a user's app can't have those permissions. Also, root permission is required.